# How can I scrape href attributes into an Array with trumpet?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the href attributes with trumpet and keep stalling at the `Object (...href attribute...) has no method 'push'` error. Same thing happens when trying to use the `createWriteStream`. The docs for this method mention a second parameter like this `elem.getAttribute(name, cb)`, but I have no idea what `cb` is.

```
var file = "...path...";
var links = [];
var trumpet = require('trumpet');
var tr = trumpet();

tr.selectAll('.list_album', function(album) {
    album.getAttribute('href').push(links);
});

var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(tr);
console.log(links);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` is a method on `Array` and your `links` object is an `Array` so it seems to me what you want to do is:

```
tr.selectAll('.list_album', function(album) {
    album.getAttribute('href', function (value) {
        links.push(value);
    });
});
```

I'm not familiar with trumpet but I'd expect this to work.

Comment: hmm, now it's just an empty array, I've also been trying to do the same thing in cheerio and can't get past the empty array either.

Comment: However! Swapping `links.push(value)` for `console.log(value)` does print all the hrefs. So, I must not be doing something right with the array.

Comment: Ok, marking this as the right answer. Pushing to the array and then writing into a txt file works smoothly, which is essentially what I needed. Thanks for the input!